# Create a new column using the non-blank value from each row using apply

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a data frame that consists of 3 columns, with each column representing the group which respondents belong to. Respondents belong to one of those groups and are tasked to provide their numerical responses in the group column that they belonged to. Hence, for a given row, 2 other columns will be blank.

I need to create a column that has their score, regardless of which group they belonged to. On Stackoverflow, there is a similar question to mine, but it is for Python (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911426/create-a-new-column-using-the-non-empty-value-from-each-row))

The following is how the data would look like and what I have done:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(grp_A = c(13, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20, NA),
             grp_B = c(NA, 59, 66, NA, NA, NA, NA),
             grp_C = c(NA, NA, NA, 23, 42, NA, NA))

df$value <- apply(select(df, grp_A, grp_B, grp_C), 1,
              function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

As there are missing data in some rows, R incorrectly converts that new column into a list. I have tried to reconvert it back into a data frame using `as.data.frame`, but it did not work.

Please kindly advise how to prevent the newly created column from turning into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R `rowMeans`

```
df$new=rowMeans(df,na.rm=T)
df
  grp_A grp_B grp_C new
1    13    NA    NA  13
2    NA    59    NA  59
3    NA    66    NA  66
4    NA    NA    23  23
5    NA    NA    42  42
6    20    NA    NA  20
7    NA    NA    NA NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `apply` since for each row you would only have one non-NA value, we could get that value using `max.col` without worrying about ties.

```
df$value <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df)))]

df
#  grp_A grp_B grp_C value
#1    13    NA    NA    13
#2    NA    59    NA    59
#3    NA    66    NA    66
#4    NA    NA    23    23
#5    NA    NA    42    42
#6    20    NA    NA    20
#7    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

`max.col` gives us the index of column number which has max value for each row and since we are wrapping it in `!is.na` it will give us the index of `TRUE`.

```
max.col(!is.na(df))
#[1] 1 2 2 3 3 1 2
```

---

The reason your `apply` didn't work is because your last row had all `NA`s and `x[!is.na(x)]` fails for it. If you remove that row and run your function then it would work

```
apply(df[-7, ], 1,function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
# 1  2  3  4  5  6 
#13 59 66 23 42 20
```

We could also find out `max` value for each row by removing `NA` but this will return `-Inf` for rows with all `NA`s

```
apply(df, 1,max, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]   13   59   66   23   42   20 -Inf
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Reduce` with `dplyr::coalesce`?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(grp_A = c(13, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20, NA),
                 grp_B = c(NA, 59, 66, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 grp_C = c(NA, NA, NA, 23, 42, NA, NA))

mutate(df, value = Reduce(coalesce, df))
```

Result:

```
  grp_A grp_B grp_C value
1    13    NA    NA    13
2    NA    59    NA    59
3    NA    66    NA    66
4    NA    NA    23    23
5    NA    NA    42    42
6    20    NA    NA    20
7    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Another option is to use `rowSums`:

```
df$value <- rowSums(df, na.rm = T)

df[df$value == 0, ] <- NA
```

Also, performance wise, base `Reduce` solution seems to be the most efficient:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Reduce = Reduce(coalesce, df), 
  purrr = purrr::reduce(df, coalesce),
  rowMeans = rowMeans(df,na.rm=T), 
  rowSums = rowSums(df, na.rm = T), 
  cbind = df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df)))],
  times = 1000
)

Unit: microseconds
     expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
   Reduce  83.507 107.2095 145.4134 121.4320 137.8410 12190.845  1000  a 
    purrr 205.667 269.1175 357.5908 304.8540 342.4135 24316.051  1000   b
 rowMeans 129.089 159.3555 196.1438 174.4890 194.9095  5481.523  1000  a 
  rowSums 129.454 157.1680 197.2731 173.5775 196.0035  7685.874  1000  a 
    cbind 267.294 331.8385 408.3179 368.4860 410.2400  4533.050  1000   b
```